# Gulp - BrowserSync doesn't reload page

Tags: css, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I'm following a basic tutorial for Gulp from [here](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/#comment-1596710) and I got stuck on the browser-sync implementation. I have copied the code exactly as it is in the example, however when I run the watch task, even though sass task executes no problem (new version of the css file is created), the browser doesn't want to refresh! Here is my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('browserSync', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    })
  })

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    // Other watchers
});
```

And here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

My styles.scss files has only one style:

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

And here is the output from the console window when I update the styles.scss

[image]

So I can see that the browser-sync is aware of the change being made, but it doesn't reload the page in the browser. Why is that? I have looked through the comments under the tutorial and no one seemed to face similar issue. I have also seen couple of other tutorials, but none of them works for me. I use latest version of chrome as my default browser, browser-sync version 5.6.0 and gulp version 3.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of piping files through `browserSync.reload` as a way to reload the dev server, and couldn't find any examples of that particular technique in the [browserSync documentation](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp). That doesn't necessarily mean that the method is invalid, but maybe the API has changed since CSS-Tricks published their tutorial in 2015? Three years can be an eternity in tooling time.

Anyway, I know I've used Gulp/browserSync/SASS successfully before so I dug up the code relevant to your situation from one of my old gulpfiles.

```
//watch task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    //spin up dev server
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        },
    });

    //when scss files change, run sass task first and reload browserSync second
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

});

//call watch task
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Basically when you call the `watch` task it immediately spins up the development server and then listens for changes to your scss files. When a change is detected, it calls the `sass` task as a dependency and runs whatever code you have for preprocessing (which you said is currently working in your file). After the `sass` task is completed, `browserSync.reload` is called via the `.on` method.

I haven't used this particular configuration in awhile but let me know if it works and if not I'd be happy to troubleshoot it with you. It's good boilerplate for any dev to have on hand.

**EDIT:** The above snippet was taken from a much larger gulpfile and upon second inspection I identified some parts that prevented it from working in a standalone context. Edited snippet to correct this.

Comment: Thanks for a reply @A.Lamansky. Unfortunately, your implementation doesn't seem to work for me as well. This time the console output is: `[10:45:34] Starting 'sass'...
[10:45:34] Finished 'sass' after 4.85 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...` but the browser still doesn't reload.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Does the new version work for you? I just tested it on my machine and it works perfectly here.

Comment: Hi @A.Lamansky, your solution still doesn't work for me. The only difference I get is `[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...` message in the console window. Unfortunately the browser still doesn't reload. Any chance you cold zip your solution and share it with me so I can run it locally and verify what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a link to the zip on my Google Drive. Note that I didn't include the node_modules folder, so you'll need to run ```npm install``` first.  Once you do that, open a terminal in the ```browsersync``` folder and run the ```gulp``` command to start the dev server. Try editing the included SCSS file to test.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZpVZHt09NONudCmGT6X3L8a7uwUhQf5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @A.Lamansky. Thanks for your help. By comparing your code with mine I finally found out that everything was alright with my solution. The only difference being - my HTML file was UTF-16 encoded. This is what must have been causing issues with browser sync code. I'm not sure how I managed to create this file with wrong encoding, since, as I remember, I created all of my files in VS Code. I've tried but couldn't reproduce that again.

Comment: Also, not sure what to do with this question. You've helped me a lot @A.Lamansky, however you simply couldn't answer my question. I'm tempted to delete it, but at the same time, I've seen similar questions to this one and I have never seen an answer suggesting to verify encoding of your files. Maybe it would be worth of keeping as a yet another reason to eliminate for whoever will face the issue in future?

Comment: @Bartosz Do whatever you feel is best. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a MAMP site and this worked for me

```
//define task
gulp.task('bsync', function () {
    //spin up dev server
    browserSync.init({
      proxy: "dev.sitename.local",
      hostname: "dev.sitename.local",
      port: 3000, //even if apache is running on 80 or something else
    });

    //when css files change, reload browserSync 
    gulp.watch('./css/*.css').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

});

//call task with 'gulp runbsync'
gulp.task('runbsync', ['bsync']);
```

https://gist.github.com/petergus/31d75a5145e062d4eaa42eb04ce23aea